# Why does a word doc attachment on my Wife’s phone show as winmail.dat?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, attachments

Note: I understand the general issues about Outlook encoding attachments, but this is about a specific device.

Our school sends out a newsletter as a .doc attachment. My Wife and I both have iPhone SE’s. I can open the attachments fine, but on my Wife’s it shows as a winmail.dat attachment and she can’t open it. We both have the same mail provider (a private mail server). Even if I forward the email I received, her phone shows it as winmail.dat. It opens OK if she views it on webmail so this is very specific to just her phone.

Her iPhone is up to date, mine is running the iOS 12 beta, but she has been having this problem before I installed the beta so I don’t think it’s related to the iOS version.

As far as I can tell, there are no settings on the phone that might control this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you both using the same mail client on your phones? If so, what are you both using? If not, what are each of you using?

Comment: @JesseP. Both using the built in mail.app.

Comment: I've found 2 discussions on Apple's forum where people had the same issues as you, dating back to 2015, where one iOS device receives the attachment correctly while another receives it as winmail.dat. Unfortunately, neither of those had a solution other than to access the email from a computer instead or to switch to a different email client (such as Outlook for iOS).

Comment: @Jesse P RE: "Anyone want to explain why my answer was downvoted even though it's 100% accurate and valid?" -- While your answer and quoted comment are deleted nonetheless, in all likelihood it was downvoted because it was a link-only answer.  Case in point if one clicks on the "here" link in your answer, one gets "The page you're looking for can't be found.". Answers need to be self-contained and not rely solely on links to other resources which, as in this case, are often broken.  One should always include enough relevant info to answer the question leaving the link as attribution/reference.

Comment: @user3439894 I understand that, and in cases where it's a forum (not an article), there are too many comments to paste in that all relate to a possible answer. Link only answers should not be deleted but should come with a disclaimer that it may no longer be valid at some point.

Comment: @user3439894 Whenever it's relevant, I provide a snippet and the link, but if I didn't here it was likely because of what I just said above.